# Handlebars templating - appending items

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm just starting out playing around with handlebars and I'm struggling to understand how to load some items on page load, then on an ajax request, load more items and append them to the content using the same template. The page loads the inital data correctly, but on the second request, all the initial data just gets overwritten.

The div to house all the content is #recipes

```
 <a href="#" id="more">Show More</a>
 <div id="recipes">

    <script id="Handlebars-Template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div id="Content">

          {{#each Recipes}}
            <div class='Box'>

                <h3>{{Name}}</h3>

            </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Recipe.php',
        success:function(data){
            var Recipes = JSON.parse(data);
            var Source = document.getElementById("Handlebars-Template").innerHTML;
             var Template = Handlebars.compile(Source);
            var HTML = Template({ Recipes : Recipes });
            document.getElementById('recipes').innerHTML +=HTML;
        }
    });
   </script>
```

and when a user clicks "Show more" the following code is run

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#more').click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
        url : 'Recipes2.php',
        success:function(data){
            var Recipes = JSON.parse(data);
            var Source = document.getElementById("Handlebars-Template").textContent;
             var Template = Handlebars.compile(Source);
             var HTML = Template({ Recipes : Recipes });
            $('#recipes').append(HTML);
        }
    })
        });
    });

    </script>
```

All the data getting returned is correct,it's just the initial data is overwritten rather than appended to.I have a feeling it's something to do with how my template is set-up  and a general lack of understanding of the templating process. I've stumbled across the idea of "partials" but not sure if this is what I should be using. Would anyone either be able to show me how something like this should be structured or point me at a useful tutorial? Everything I've seen seems to focus on replacing all the data, or only works on an initial load.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've worked out how to do what I want, but I'm not really sure if it is the best solution to this issue or if I'm doing things correctly.

I think the problem is that my template sits within the div I'm trying to append to ('#recipes') If I move #recipes to be a container on it's own (i.e. with the template not inside it) Then this works. I'm not 100% sure what's going on under the hood, but if I revise my html to a structure such as follows, this works.  I'll leave this question open for others to fully explain this for a couple of days rather than clicking my own answer to see if anyone can shed light on why this is.

thanks

```
<div id="recipes"></div><!--Recipes no longer encloses the template -->
    <script id="Handlebars-Template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
          {{#each Recipes}}
            <div class='Box'>
                <h3>{{Name}}</h3>

            </div>
          {{/each}}

    </script>
```

**** UPDATE
It looks like the issue was down to styling. The expected results were there, but the styling from a tutorial was using absolute positioning, so it looked like the results weren't updating. However there were other issues, with the fact that some content was sitting within the template that shouldn't have been, so some javascript events weren't firing correctly, due to overwriting the innerHTML that contained the template initially (so on the 2nd run the template no longer existed)